# Load steam applist as JSON file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, steam

I've been trying to load the Steam app list from this url "https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2/?key=XXXXXXXXXetc." and I've tried all combinations I think, with AJAX, downloading it using PHP, but I haven't been able to find a way that works, hope you can help!

Thanks in advance, Magn0053

Comment: Use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: I tried but... I can't get it to work since it's a JSON file already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$jsonString = file_get_content("https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2/?key=XXXXXXXXXetc");

$listArray = json_decode($jsonString, true);
echo "<ul id="listResults">\r\n";
foreach($listArray as $k => $v){
    echo "<li><label>$k</label>: $v</li>\r\n";
}
echo "</ul>\r\n";
?>
```

This can be done in JQuery too (Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/be5h65L3/):

```
$(function(){
    $("#getListBtn").click(function(){
        var url = 'https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2/?key=XXXXXXXXXetc&callback=?';

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            async: false,
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data) {
               $.each(data, function(k, v){
                   $("#listResults").append("<li><label>" + k + "<label>: " + v + "</li>");
               });
            },
            error: function(e) {
               console.log(e.message);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: When I try to use the jquery (which I'd like most to use) I get error "XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2/?key=61942B63591E24CE5AF41D364F69D326. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://magnus.nielsfyhring.dk' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: And if I'm trying the php version I get this error
"Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\giveaway\pages\steamapplist.php on line 9
applist: Array"

Comment: Hasty response, edited and changed to use JSONP so you get past cross-site issues.